# Material autocomplete panel issue

Tags: angular, angular-material

In my angular 4 project I have an issue with Material autocomplete.
When I type something and the component shows suggestions if I scroll the page I see the suggestions panel unlinked from the autocomplete field like you see in the picture.
But in the [Material-Autocomplete](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview) I don't have this issue.

This is my code:

```
<mat-form-field>
        <input matInput placeholder="{{'customer.detail.labels.country'
          | translate }}" required [matAutocomplete]="tdAuto" name="country" #country="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="selected.country"
          (ngModelChange)="searchCountry($event)"> </mat-form-field>
            <mat-autocomplete #tdAuto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn">
            <mat-option (onSelectionChange)="setCountry(country)" *ngFor="let country of countries" [value]="country">
                <div class="row">
                  <img src="assets/img/flags24/{{country.alpha2Code | lowercase}}.png" />
                    <span>{{country.name}} ({{country.alpha2Code}})</span>
                </div>
            </mat-option>
        </mat-autocomplete>
```

[image]

Comment: The `<mat-form-field>` should be around the whole autocomplete not only the input. Not sure if taht fixes it though

Comment: @Shadowlauch unfortunately no, it doesn't

Comment: @Alessandro Could you specify which version of angular material are you using?

Comment: @The.Bear yes sorry, I am using "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.12" and angular 4.4.4

Comment: this is still happening in the newest version of angular/material, whats happening is the scroll events are never being bound onto the container overlay - also it doesn't happen if the component isn't nested in a layout

Answer (score 0):

Use CdkScrollable in your component. Also add it to imports in your module file.